# Time calcuation for each method in a package.

Tags: java, spring

Is there any way to calculate time taken for each method in a package(which contains no of classes)? Instead of package starting time and ending time of each method. Is there any other options?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: have you looked at AOP?

Comment: If you need this only once, but not for ever, than have a look at a Java Profiler

Comment: check this tips on profiling your app: https://www.infoq.com/articles/java-profiling-with-open-source/

Comment: @Pravin Sonawane .... I tried with AOP, however it is not set for the requirement. It only giving time for individual method. If I call another method inside a method then it is not able to find the inner method time to execute

Comment: You can apply an `Aspect` to all methods. This will give you times for methods being called by other methods as well. AspectJ handles `private` methods too.

Comment: Is it work for this code: public void doSomething(){ xyzclass.execute()} . I need to calculate the time for both doSomething and execute method in xyzclass. By using AOP I can able to calculate only doSomething() but not execute() method. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

With AspectJ you can use .around() annotation:

```
@Aspect
public class TimedAnnotation {
    @Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(TimedMethod)")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {

            Object p = point.proceed();

            return p;
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
        }
    }
}
```

You'll still have to put this annotation for each method:

```
@TimedMethod
public void doSomething() {
...
}
```

And you'll need to add AspectJ to your pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Is it work for this code: public void doSomething(){ xyzclass.execute()} . I need to calculate the time for both doSomething and execute method in xyzclass.

Comment: If you control xyzclass, you can put @TimedMethod around .execute() too.